# Nominalization of the phrase “the way they are normally represented”

Tags: verbs, nouns, technical

In a past exam on technical writing, we were required to rewrite the italicized part of the following clause using nominalization, that is, turning verb phrases to noun phrases:

> "[...] this approach has the ability to also recognize patterns that are modified from *the way they are normally presented*. [...]"

I might try rewriting it as "the way of their normal presentation."  This sounds a bit weird to me, and I'm not sure if it is common to put a noun phrase after "the way of" in this meaning of "way".

How would you answer this problem?

EDIT: I misquoted the question a bit: the word *presented* was *represented* originally.

Comment: I’d probably just get rid of ‘the way of’ altogether: “[…] patterns that are modified from _their normal presentation_.”

Comment: May I ask why this question should be in ELU rather than in ELL?  I'm a English language learner!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The way they are normally presented* is a relative clause, with some parts missing.
It comes from *the way **that** they are normally presented*, but *that* has been deleted.
This is common with relative clauses modifying *way*; they have to use *that*, because the *wh*-word that one would normally associate with *the way* is *how*, but *how* can't be used as a relative pronoun:

- *the time **that** they arrive ~ the time they arrive ~ the time **when** they arrive*
- *the place **that** you found it ~ the place you found it ~ the place **where** you found it*
- *the way **that** he did it ~ the way he did it*,   **but**   **the way how he did it*

The manner nominalization of *present* is *presentation*, and *normal* can modify it.
The problem is getting the subject *they* in; nouns don't have subjects.

However, the usual situation for nominalizing a clause is to add the subject as a possessive.
Thus, *their normal presentation* does the job. You don't need *the way* any more.
The nominalization *their presentation* **means** *the way they're presented*.
This is one of the benefits of nominalizing, if you're careful.

Answer (score -1):

Taking a wild guess;"[...] this approach has the ability to also recognize patterns that are modified from their [nominal] or “face value” perception [...]"